# Queryset to call ModelFormField into Chart JS - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I am attempting to pass user submitted data from a django model form into a Chart.js chart that renders on a detail view page. I think in order to pass the data from the instance of the model form submission in my view.py to the js which renders the chart I need to construct a queryset. I have been unable to figure out how to write the correct queryset in order to pass the integer values for the two specific fields for the instance of the form submission (listed below).

When I hardcode values into my class-based view defined variables for TAM and LTM_sales the chart renders. Please see code below:

**Models.py:**

```
class Strategy(models.Model):
    total_addressable_market = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_twelve_months_sales = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
def strategy_detail(request, id):
    strategy = get_object_or_404(Strategy, id=id)
    ....
    context ={
        'strategy': strategy,
        ....
    }
    return render(request,'hypo_app/strategy_detail.html', context)

class ChartData(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    
    def get(self, request, default=None):
        strategy = Strategy.objects.all()
        TAM = ??
        LTM_sales = ??
        labels = ['TAM', 'LTM Revenue']
        default_items = [TAM, LTM_sales]
        data = {
        "labels": labels,
        "default": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

**URL**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserExperimentListView, ChartData
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('chart_data/', ChartData.as_view(), name='chart_data'),
]
```

**JAVASCRIPT within the strategy_detail.html file**

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/chart_data/'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.default
        setChart()
    },

    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Market Share',
                    data: defaultData,
```

**forms.py** (per comment request)

```
from django import forms
from .models import Experiment, Thread, Strategy
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime, date


class StrategyCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Strategy
        fields = (
            ....
            'total_addressable_market',
            'last_twelve_months_sales',
        )
```

Comment: The convention for submitting form data is via POST method, not GET. For returning a queryset based upon form data, use ORM method called [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters).

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I am rendering a view based on submitted data from the modelform in my strategy detail page. Then I am trying to pass the submitted data to the chart.js. So I was thinking that the chart.js must rely on a get function in order to retreive that model form field submission.